# appending select-box value to href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box with few options.
e.g

```
<select>
   <option value="India">India</option>
   <option value="Usa">Usa</option>
  </select>
```

I have href element as below and i want the value of selected option in select box to be appended to the href link, while clicking the href element. lets say name=India.

e.g `<a href="http://localhost:8080/country?name=">Visit Country</a>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var old_href = $('a').attr('href'),
        new_href = old_href.split('=')[0] + '=' + this.value;
    $('a').attr('href', new_href);
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you do this without the split? Just new_href = old_href + this.value;

Comment: ^^ Ah, nice. I see the logic now